# Python json POST request status 200 while expecting status 201

Tags: python, json, http, post

I'm trying to do a POST request to a web server in an attempt to create a new resource. I'm fairly new to both Python and the platform I'm trying to communicate with on the server, so I'm not sure if it's my python skills require a bit more practice or if I'm just not submitting a request correctly to the server. Here's my code:

```
import requests

apiKey = "[APIKEY]"
serverUrl = "http://192.168.0.5/api/v1.0/payments"

values = """
  {
    "clientId": 1,
    "method": 3,
    "createdDate": "2016-09-12T00:00:00+0000",
    "amount": 10,
    "note": "",
    "invoiceIds": []
  }
"""


headers = {
  'X-Auth-App-Key': apiKey,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

r = requests.post(serverUrl, data=values, headers=headers)
r
```

The server responds with a Response 200 (OK) message, but since I'm trying to create a new resource it should respond with a Response 201 (Created) message. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you own, manage or can see the code for the server application?

Comment: I do own the server, but the application I'm using is not open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `https://`,

change `serverUrl = "http://192.168.0.5/api/v1.0/payments"`

to

```
serverUrl = "https://192.168.0.5/api/v1.0/payments"
```

Comment: Tried that (after changing url to FQDN name with proper SSL cert) and now it's giving me a 422 Unprocessable Entity response. Does this mean the server doesn't take the values I'm passing in as the data?

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't result in a different HTTP status code, but you can send JSON encoded dictionaries directly by using the `json` parameter to `requests.post()`. So `values` can be a dictionary, and `requests` will set the content type so you don't need to in `headers`:

```
values =
  {
    "clientId": 1,
    "method": 3,
    "createdDate": "2016-09-12T00:00:00+0000",
    "amount": 123.45,
    "note": "",
    "invoiceIds": []
  }

headers = {'X-Auth-App-Key': apiKey}

r = requests.post(serverUrl, json=values, headers=headers)
```

It's just a little cleaner.

Regarding the expected 201 response, is the resource actually created? Do you get a 201 response when using other tools such as `curl`?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, for now I just want to make sure that the code will actually work, then I'll move on to other things like tidying up the code.
The resource is not created on the server and I've no experience with curl whatsoever.

Comment: @Detoxica: I have managed to use this code to make a payment on the UCRM test service at https://ucrm-demo.ubnt.com/api/v1.0/payments . HTTP response is 201 and the resource is created. I used the test write app key found at http://ucrm-demo.ubnt.com/system/security/app-keys/2 (just sign in as admin). I also had to change the `amount` to a proper monetary value, e.g. `"amount": 123.45`

Comment: @Detoxica: I have also tried it successfully with your code. All I changed was the `amount` value.

Comment: Probably there is something about your server, maybe the web server frontending it. Could it be redirecting your request because your URL does not end with a `/`? Try making the request with `r = requests.post(...)` and then checking `r.history`. If the request was redirected it could be using `GET` without the JSON body, and maybe that gives you a 200 response. Try appending a `/` to `serverUrl`.

Comment: Brilliant, that's working for me too now. I'll post on the UCRM forums that the API guides should be updated because their example code had "10" as the value.
Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Comment: @Detoxica: that does not explain why you are seeing 200 instead of 201. My testing shows an incorrect `amount` field results in response code 422.

Comment: @Detoxica: OK, looking at the answer by Surajano I see that the problem is a combination of not using SSL and an incorrect amount field. Weird that it would return a 200 when using an insecure socket. It makes no difference on the test server.